# Númber of active repositories in GitHub info site differs from advanced search tool result

Tags: github, github-api

I was trying to fetch the number of active repositories in GitHub filtering by language. The http://githut.info/ informs that for JavaScript for example, the number of active repositories is almost 324k at actual date, but the advanced search ( https://github.com/search/advanced ) fetchs different results. Every time I click on the button "search", the results vary a lot. It is a GitHub error or I am misinterpreting the results ? What is the correct number of active repositories for the JavaScript language ? Last search attempts results were: 
1,165,044 - 1,113,619 - 1,562,297.

Comment: Why don't you contact GitHub about it?

Comment: Because maybe I could be misinterpreting the data.. so I preferred to ask here first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice the question mark next to the number of results, which links to this part of the documentation:

https://help.github.com/articles/searching-github/#potential-timeouts

Does that answer your question about different numbers in search results?

Also, http://githut.info/ is not developed by GitHub, so I don't think those numbers would be considered "official".

Comment: yeah I suppose this is the answer for that Ivan. Thanks. I would vote you up if I had enough reputation for that :/

Comment: @Digao Since you consider this to be the correct answer, don't forget to mark it by clicking the `✔` button in the left side of the answer. You will also get 2 reputation points for that and Ivan will receive the points he deserves. `:-)`